# How to display replies to his comments in user profile of current user

Tags: comments, comment-form, wp-user-query, comments-template

How to display list of replies to his comments in user profile of current user. my website can send notification that example: "someone replied to your comment" and when i click the  link that was sent by notification email it forward me to comment page. i also want to list these replies  in user profile.
thanks for attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a page where I list comments and replies to the current user comments.

I might not be able to explain the answer very well, but this is what I did. I listed all the comments of the current user and listed again the comments with the parent_id of the current user's comments.

```
$comments = get_comments( array(
                            'user_id' => (get_current_user_id()),
                            'status'  => array( 'approve', 'hold' ),
                            'type'  => 'comment'
                            )
                        );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
                                
    echo  $comment->comment_content;
    
    $parent_id = $comment->comment_ID;
                                
    $replies = get_comments( array(
                                'status'  => array( 'approve', 'hold' ),
                                'type'  => 'comment',
                                'parent' => $parent_id
                                )
                            );
    foreach ( $replies as $reply ) {
        echo $reply->comment_author;
        echo $reply->comment_content;
        }
}
```

In a WordPress environment this is the best way I have come up with.

Comment: thank you very much i wil test it now

Comment: Thank you very much it works

Comment: How can we give comment link to replies

Comment: Try `get_comment_link()` : something like `<a href="<?php echo get_comment_link(); ?>"><?php echo $reply->comment_author;?></a>`